# How to solve this error org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: %

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to make simple search bar using spring and MySQL query. I used the below code to get list of customers but I'm getting error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: %.

Code I used:

```
public List<CustDTO> getCust(String name) throws Exception {
  List<CustDTO> customerList=null;

  String queryString ="SELECT c FROM Cust c WHERE c.name LIKE %?1%";
  Query query=entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
  query.setParameter(1, name);
    
  List<Cust> result = query.getResultList();

  customerList=new ArrayList<CustDTO>();

    for (Cust customerEntity : result) {
        CustDTO customer=new CustDTO();
        customer.setName(customerEntity.getName());
        customer.setCity(customerEntity.getCity());

        customerList.add(customer);
    }
    System.out.println(customerList);
    return customerList;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, Hibernate won't let you do that.
If you want your  like query to work, use:

```
   String queryString ="SELECT c FROM Cust c WHERE c.name LIKE ?1";
    Query query=entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
    query.setParameter(1, "%"+name+"%”);
```

Or you can even use a native query.

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<CustDTO> getCust(String theSearchName) throws Exception {

Query theQuery = null;

theQuery = createQuery("from CustDTO where lower(name) like :theName", CustDTO.class);
query.setParameter("theName", "%" + theSearchName.toLowerCase() + "%");

    List<CustDTO> customers = theQuery.getResultList();
                
    return customers;
```

lower(**name**) - name is the field from your CustDTO entity.

You can also add checks if your input is empty or not

```
if (theSearchName != null && theSearchName.trim().length() > 0) {

        // do search with like
    }else {
        // theSearchName is empty ... so just get all customers
        theQuery =currentSession.createQuery("from CustDTO", CustDTO.class);            
    }
```